# Distribution of values of the chi square pdf

Tags: fitting, chi-squared-distribution

In short: if $Z$ is chi square with $n>1$ degrees of freedom and $f_Z$ its density function, and $X=f_Z(Z)$, what is the distribution of $X$ (in particular its mean and variance)?

Explanation:

I want to estimate a value $x$ and have candidate estimates $x_1,...,x_n$. For each candidate I can calculate a chi square score with 4 degrees of freedom comparing it to $x$; call it $z_i$. I am then forming the weighted average
$$
\frac{\sum_i f_Z(z_i)x_i}{\sum_i f_Z(z_i)}
$$
as my estimate of $x$, so, assuming the necessary independence, the variance of my estimate will be a complicated formula for the variance of a quotient that I found, which breaks down into linear combinations of $E(X)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ with $X$ as in the first paragraph.

Bonus question:

Is what I'm doing at all legitimate or a known method? In case it isn't clear, while I have a grounding in probability, I know next to nothing about statistics. Many thanks for any pointers or alternative suggestions.

Comment: If you would tell us the *statistical* problem you are trying to address with this method, we might be able to help you out.  Frankly, it looks erroneous (but maybe in your specific application it could be meaningful), so you might not want to spend the time and effort working out this distribution (which is complicated) until you're sure it's a good approach.

Comment: I have not seen this before and I do not see a reason for weighting observations by densities.  For what it is worth, if $Z \sim \chi^2_4$ and $X$ is $f(Z)$ where $f$ is the density of $Z$ then empirically $E[X]=0.125$ and $Var(X) \approx 0.00289352$.  If $Z \sim \chi^2_\nu$ then it seems  $E[X]=\frac{\Gamma(\nu-1)}{\Gamma(\nu/2) 2^{\nu}}$ and there may be a more complicated expression for the variance

Comment: * I can calculate a chi square score with 4 degrees of freedom comparing it to $x$* -  isn't $x$ what you are trying to estimate?  How can you compare if you don't know it?

Comment: Thanks for the calculation and question. To clarify: These are astronomical objects; the one with unknown $x$ has other known properties, and my chi square score compares these to the properties in a grid of related objects for which I also know the $x$-value ($x_i$). It does feel iffy, but isn't the pdf a reasonable measure of how "likely" a particular chi square score is? I'm at a loss for how to get an estimate for $x$ from the $x_i$ estimates otherwise.

Comment: @JohnBourke the problem is your $Z$ is chi-square distributed only under the assumption that all the measurements have the same means, but if I understand your problem correctly this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of the technique that you are using.  It also seems that you are considering an uncommon transformation.  If I'm understanding correctly, the base variable is $Z \sim \chi^2_n$ and the transformed variable $X = f_Z(Z)$, the probability density function (pdf) of $Z$.  To be precise, we consider the transformation
$$
X = \frac{1}{2^{n/2} \Gamma \left(n/2\right)}Z^{n/2-1} \exp \left(-Z/2\right).
$$
In order to find the pdf of the transformed variable, $X$, we need to find the inverse of the above equation.  The transformation is one-to-one and the support remains unchanged; however, there is no closed-form solution for the inverse of $X$.  The inverse function can be shown to be a Lambert W-function.  Specifically,
$$
Z(X) = -(n-2)W\left(- \frac{\left(2^{n/2} \Gamma \left(n/2\right)X\right)^{2/(n-2)}}{(n-2)}\right).
$$
Therefore, by definition, the pdf of $X$ is
$$
f_X(x) = f_Z(Z(x)) \left| \frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{d} x} Z(x) \right|, \quad x>0,
$$
where the derivative of the Lambert W-function can be simplified.

If one wants to find the moments of $X$, then its a question of evaluating powers of the density of a $\chi^2$ random variable.  Using the first formula, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{E}[X] &=& \frac{1}{2^{n/2} \Gamma \left(n/2\right)} \mbox{E}\left[Z^{n/2-1} \exp \left(-Z/2\right)\right] \\
&=& \frac{1}{2^{n} \Gamma^2 \left(n/2\right)} \int_0^{\infty} z^{n-2} \exp(-z) \mbox{d} z \\
&=& \frac{\Gamma(n-1)}{2^{n} \Gamma^2 \left(n/2\right)} \\
&=& \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})}{4\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right) }.
\end{eqnarray*}